# How to convert a 13 digit unix epoch time format to date time?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, epoch

I'm trying to transform a data frame column containing a 13 digit unix epoch time log into human readable date-time log format.

Here's what I've tried:

```
alerts[date_time] = alerts['epoch'].map(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(alerts['epoch'], origin='unix', unit = 'ms'))
```

However, I noticed that all 43 thousand rows of my data frame had the same value despite different epoch time logs. Can someone help?

Comment: `df['date_time']` should under the quote

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong syntax of `to_datetime` as part of a map.

You simply need to do:

```py
alerts['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(alerts['epoch'], origin='unix', unit = 'ms')
```